# Pass URL Parameter from Javascript to Flash Object in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have no HTML knowledge, I just have a simple task that I can't seem to grasp the concept of doing.

I want to take a url parameter and pass it to a swf object. I've figured out getting the parameter via javascript, but getting that return string to the object is my issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    return "http://www.Twitch.tv/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf?channel=twitch";
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="this.href=myFunction()">Link Example</a>

<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" width="800" height="600"  id="mymoviename"> 

<embed src="#" onload="this.src=myFunction()" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff"
width="800" height="600" 
name="mymoviename" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"> 

</embed> 
</object>

</body>
</html>
```

Markup based on Suggested answer(still does not work)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>  
<a href="#" onclick="this.href=myFunction()">Link Example</a>

<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"  
width="800" height="600" id="mymoviename"> 

<embed src="#" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="800" height="600" 
name="mymoviename" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"> 
</embed> 
</object>

<script> 
function myFunction() {
    return "http://www.Twitch.tv/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf?channel=twitch";      
}
document.getElementById('mymoviename').src = myFunction();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<a onclick="myFunction(2,2);">Link Example</a>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following the following steps.

1. Move your `<script>` to just before `</body>`
2. And add the below code in `<script>`:

Code:

```
function myFunction() {
    return "http://www.Twitch.tv/swflibs/TwitchPlayer.swf?channel=twitch";
}
document.getElementById('mymoviename').src = myFunction();
```

Comment: Basically, my end goal is to load a url to an embedded flash object. The line I need to generate based on the function return is:
<embed src=ENTERURLHERE quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff">
How does your example apply outside of the href tag?

Comment: @bill I gave solution to the example. The rest is for you to figure

Comment: I'm simply asking if your example works inside an object as well.

Comment: @bill replace `this.href` with `this.src`

Comment: I tried using your example for this.href, and I uploaded the page to my website. It did not work, instead the link directed to the same page with # appended.

Comment: your edit now works with a link, but using onclick isn't useful for using on the flash object. I tried:
<embed src="#" onload="this.src=myFunction()" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff"

and it still tries to load "#" instead of the function

Comment: I updated the main question to be more clear on my issue

Comment: @bill is that your markup original? so that I'll be able to answer you.

Comment: I updated the main post with just my original markup

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer so it will be even more complete?

Comment: The movie player is still not receiving the return string

Comment: I figured out a solution that works. I'll put it up an answer.

Comment: @bill congrats for solving it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

I found this article: 
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashVars/

Instead of passing the javascript variable to html markup, just write the markup with the script itself. Here is the working code:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Example</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
 var myQueryString=document.location.search;

 // remove the '?' sign if exists
 if (myQueryString[0]='?')
 {
myQueryString=myQueryString.substr(3, myQueryString.length-1);
 }

 document.write(
 '<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"   codebase="http://macromedia.com/cabs/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="250" HEIGHT="250" id="flaMovie1"> <embed src="'+myQueryString+'" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="800" height="600" name="mymoviename" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">\n'+
'</embed>\n'+   
'</OBJECT>');

 </SCRIPT>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```